# Как я могу передать переменную в функцию к которой применен valueChanged?

Tags: python, qt, pyqt5, pyside2

Мне нужно передать переменную в функцию. Я пробовал это сделать через `lambda`, но почему-то функция не видит переменную `val`.

```
    menuAnimation = QtCore.QVariantAnimation()
    menuAnimation.valueChanged.connect(lambda val=1: self.resizeMenu(val))

def resizeMenu(self,value,val=''):
    print(val)
```

Как это исправить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
    menuAnimation = QtCore.QVariantAnimation()
    # menuAnimation.valueChanged.connect(lambda val=1: self.resizeMenu(val))
    menuAnimation.valueChanged.connect(lambda value, val=1: self.resizeMenu(value, val))

def resizeMenu(self, value, val=''):
    print(val)
```